# Sound not always playing with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to play sound on the browser:

**HTML**

```
<audio id="' + newMessageSoundObjectId + '"><source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

**Javascript**

```
this.newMessageSoundObject = document.getElementById(newMessageSoundObjectId);
// ...
var playPromise = this.newMessageSoundObject.play();
if (playPromise !== undefined) {
    playPromise.then(function() {
      // Automatic playback started!
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Sound was not played: " + error);
     });
}
```

It works well most of the time, but sometimes it randomly stops working for a few minutes and starts again, without reloading the page or navigating. Moreover, console doesn't error any error.

For more context, this is used to play a notification when a user receives a new message.

Is there a better way to ensure sound is played?

Comment: Could it be the browser disabling audio playback or muting audio to prevent annoyances for users - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Playing needs to be started by user interaction such as a click

Comment: I know about the need for user interaction, and it would fail the Promise and output in the console. User interaction happens, it works for a a few minutes to a few hours, then stop working for a couple of minutes, and starts again.

Answer (score 5):

You may be running into the situation where it waits to finish the clip before responding to any new clicks.

If so, insert this code at the beginning of your function to reset the clip each time it is clicked:

```
audio.currentTime = 0; // On each click, rewind clip to start
```

It would look something like this:

```
if (playPromise !== undefined) {
    playPromise.then(function() {
    audio.currentTime = 0; // On each click, rewind clip to start
      // Automatic playback started!
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Sound was not played: " + error);
     });
```

You may want to consider adjusting your code so it's a bit cleaner. I haven't tested this, but it should work just fine:

```
const soundObject = document.querySelector("#newMessageSoundObjectId");

soundObject.addEventListener("mousedown", playClip);

function playClip() {
    audio.currentTime = 0; // On each click, rewind clip to start
    audio.play();
} else {
    console.error("Something went wrong");
```